Change date interval in aldabil's react-scheduler
I'm using aldabil's react-scheduler component for my app. I need to change the date interval shown in the month view. What I want to achieve is to show in the view 1 week before my current date and 30 days in advance. In this example, the 09 - 15 week should be top row and the last should be the week of Jan 6 to Jan 12.

I want to only show the current week in the top row and then the following 3/4 weeks. So i can keep track of last events and the upcoming ones without having so much bloat.
Reading the docs I found that you can pass a ref to the calendar and manage various stuff from it, like this:
calendarRef.current.scheduler.handleState(value, key);

For changing the view from a button input, this works wonderfully:
schedulerRef.current.scheduler.handleState("day", "view");

By console logging schedulerRef.current.scheduler I can see a selectedRange property, but when assigning values to that nothing seems to change
 <button
        onClick={() => {
          console.log(schedulerRef.current.scheduler);

          schedulerRef.current.scheduler.handleState(
            {
              start: new Date(2024, 11, 9),
              end: new Date(2025, 0, 10),
            },
            "selectedRange"
          );
        }}
      >
        Some Component
      </button>

